# Access VBA: Why do I get a duplicate declaration error if I am making sure to set the object to Nothing before re-using?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, ms-access-2013

I have code that looks like this:

```
If BLAH=BLAH

        Dim dbs As DAO.Database
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

...rest of code...

        'Close stuff
        rst.Close
        dbs.Close
        Set dbs = Nothing
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set qdf = Nothing

END IF

If FOO=FOO

        Dim dbs As DAO.Database
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

...rest of code...

        'Close stuff
        rst.Close
        dbs.Close
        Set dbs = Nothing
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set qdf = Nothing

END IF
```

But in the `FOO=FOO` section, it highlighted `dbs As DAO.Database` and gave a pop-up error message that says

> Compile error: duplicate declaration in current scope.

What am I doing wrong? I thought this would be ok because I am negating each object before re-using. The overarching goal is to run a ton of `IF` statements on the Form Timer event. Do I need to maybe just declare some objects only once at the top of the event procedure to get around this error?

Comment: Exactly what it says, you're declaring it twice, you only need to Dim once.  So just before your first if do the dim, then no need, just use them

Comment: Yea, I was fiddling it around while waiting and simply commenting out the other `Dim`'s made the error go away. I'm now curious as to why using the code under "Close stuff" didn't negate the initialization of those objects.

Comment: Using `Dim` just tells the compiler "I'm going to be using a variable named `X` of type `Y`" - it's independent of actually populating or clearing that variable (except when you use `Dim X As New Y`)  Setting a variable to Nothing doesn't remove the variable itself, it remains but no longer points to any object.

Comment: Its like saying if you have a house with a garage, but sell your car, you'll still have a garage, so when you are closing them, they still exist.  They are properly destroyed at the end of their scope  
`Dim a As Excel.Workbook
Set a = Workbooks.Add
Debug.Print TypeName(a)
Set a = Nothing
Debug.Print TypeName(a)
Set a = Workbooks.Add
Debug.Print TypeName(a)`

Comment: Also be aware of the difference between Compile errors and Runtime errors. What you describe in your question could only be detected at runtime. But you get a Compile error, so whether you set or not set a variable can't have any influence. /sherlock

Answer (score 3):

To clear this issue up in the case of VBA, variable declares are global to the given sub/function routine, or even to the given module.

For most here, the posters question seems strange, but keep in mind that in vb.net the variable definctions are LOCAL to a if/then block of code as posted.

This in VBA, this fails, but in vb.net, it is perfectally legal:

```
    If True Then
        Dim a As Long
        a = 5
    End If

    If True Then
        Dim a As Long
        a = 6
    End If
```

And if you wanted the variable able to be used in both if/then blocks, then you would use this:

```
    Dim a As Long
    If True Then
        a = 5
    End If

    If True Then
        a = 6
    End If
```

So in VBA, variable scope is local to the function/subroutine. In vb.net the scope is local to the if/then block. This means in some programming languages you can declare a variable several times in a function/subroutine and not receive any compile errors – even when option explicit is in effect. I should also point out that in the above vb.net code examples when code drops out of the if/then block, then the given variable in the first code example goes out of scope. So in VBA, variable declares are not local to a if/then block. I should also point out that I used the word “local” scope, since the if/then code is compiled, and the if/then of the “dim” statement does NOT occur at runtime, but at compile time.  In other words, "true" or "false" does not mean the "dim" and declare of the variable does not occur, but only that the variable is "local" to the if/then block. The dim statement does NOT run conditional and is created at compile time.